# Flash data is not being retrieved in Codeigniter Redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

Welcome Contoller of my code

```
public function admission()
{

    if($this->module_lib->hasActive('online_admission')){


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {


    } else {

        if ($document_validate) {


            $insert_id = $this->onlinestudent_model->add($data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">' . $this->lang->line('success_message') . '</div>');

            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
        }

        $this->load_theme('pages/admission');
    }

    }
}
```

View code

```
?php
if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) {
    echo $this->session->flashdata('response');
    $message = $this->session->flashdata('msg');

    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <?php echo $this->lang->line('success_message')?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Here the flashdata is not being loaded when we refresh, when we use `$this->load_theme('pages/admission')`; this instead of refresh code instead of `redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');` at this senario we can get flashdata but  the data inside the form will be there it's not being refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Where `$document_validate` and `$data` is defined ?

Try the following code and let me know the result

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    $this->load_theme('pages/admission');
} else{
    $insert_id = $this->onlinestudent_model->add($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">' . $this->lang->line('success_message') . '</div>');
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: same, no change